# how to first triangulation or begining triangulation happen in mesh creation

Tags: mesh, triangulation, delaunay

now I started to learn Delaunay triangulation in that I cannot find how to beginning triangulation happened

now my question is we have some cloud point example 10 points without the triangulation method how I can do triangulation in my points

and if I do triangulation using algorithm(Delaunay) means how first or beginning triangulation happen

know persons come forward with code

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an incremental algorithm (i.e. an insertion algorithm), a common solution is to pick 3 points at random and construct the first triangle in a dedicated block of code. If you look at the "bootstrap" treatment in the open- source Tinfour project you'll find lots of documentation in the code.  The PDF document I cited the other day has diagrams illustrating the process. See http://tinfour.org

That being said,  there are other algorithms such as the popular "divide and conquer " that don't need a bootstrap phase of processing.

Hope this helps